# Limit Plotting Issue

Tags: plotting

I recently installed Wolfram Mathematica and attempted to graph a limit, but it seems that it refuses to do so. The equation is $\lim_{x\to e^-}\frac{e}{e-x}$ and the input is **Plot[Limit[Divide[e, e - x], x -> e, Direction -> 1], {x,1, 4}]**

It displays this graphic and these errors when executed:

```
Plot[Limit[Divide[e, e - x], x -> e, Direction -> 1], {x, 1, 4}]

Limit: 1.0000612857142857` is not a valid variable.
Limit: 1.0000612857142857` is not a valid variable.
Limit: 1.061285775510204` is not a valid variable.
General: Further output of Limit::ivar will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

[image]

Can anyone explain to me why the issue is occurring, and how to fix it?

Comment: Before trying to do the plot command, have you tried to look at what is it you want to plot, by issuing the command `Limit[e/(e - x), x -> e, Direction -> 1]` before to see what it generates? That is always useful to do.

Comment: Putting aside Mathematica for a moment, can you explain what you want to do in plain English? Clearly, if you take a limit for $x$, the result will no longer contain $x$. Yet you are trying to plot according to  $x$. It is not at all clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Nasser I tried that, and it outputs e ∞ , implying that the limit is equal to infinity. I already knew that beforehand, I just wanted to know how to plot it. Thanks for the suggestion anyway though.

Comment: @Szabolcs I understand that it will not contain x, but my issue is not whether it does or not but that the limit I put does not display graphically. The issue I am having that I want to be solved is that I want it to display the plot. On other software, it does so just fine but I was curious as to why it does not on Mathematica. Maybe this explanation doesn't make sense or I don't understand your question, but this is the issue I'm having.

Comment: `and it outputs e ∞` Correct. But then what do you expect that `Plot[e*Infinity, {x, 1, 4}]` to generate? since `e` even has no numerical value.  Even `Plot[Infinity, {x, 1, 4}]` produces empty plot since `Infinity` is not a number.  Now one can do `Plot[5, {x, 1, 4}]`  and that works. But not when the quantity being printed has symbols with no value in them (other than `x` ofcourse)

Comment: @Nasser My question was already answered but I'll respond regardless since I'm still interested. I might be ignorant right now but does the program not recognize e as Euler's Number...? Now that I think about it you make total sense lol. I never really specified what it was equal to. It probably thought I was just referring to a variable e.

Comment: in Mathematica Euler number is `Exp[1]`, of just `E`  Mathematica is case sensitive.  so `e` is nothing special, just a symbol like `x` and `y`

Comment: @Nasser Huh, I'll definitely note that. No wonder why Syed's solution had E in it. Okay, I think I get that part at least now. Thanks for the clarification and quick response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limit gives you a number (if it exists). Plot this function instead with some related options to get more insight.

```
Plot[E/(E - x), {x, 1, 4}, Exclusions -> Automatic, 
 ExclusionsStyle -> {Dashed, Red}]
```

[image]

The limit can be calculated separately and in your case, it is `Indeterminate`.

```
Limit[E/(E - x), x -> E, Direction -> "TwoSided"]
```

If you search the docs for Limit, you will find other options for `Direction` that you can try out.

Comment: Wow, I guess I really am inexperienced lol. Thank you, that worked just fine. Much appreciated.

Comment: @böldpest Introductory book by the inventor: https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/ ; For math students: https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/

Comment: Ah, I'll definitely read up on it now that you mention it. Thanks again.